# How to fix "Undefined array key"

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have problem every time I try to actualize Elementor from 3.9.2 to 3.10 - I see an error
"Warning: Undefined array key "file" in (...)/wp-includes/media.php on line 1680".
It appears at the bottom of my homepage. After backup everything's working well.

The code is:

```
// Bail early if an image has been inserted and later edited.
if ( preg_match( '/-e[0-9]{13}/', $image_meta['file'], $img_edit_hash ) &&
    strpos( wp_basename( $image_src ), $img_edit_hash[0] ) === false ) {

    return $image;
}
```

I'm a noob un php so I need some help to fix it. Don't know what to do.
It may be helpful to know that I have set short film as a background in first section on homepage.

I tried to find this array definition but I have no idea wehere it is.
I used @ in code but I know it's not recommended so I want to find better solution

```
// Bail early if an image has been inserted and later edited.
if ( preg_match( '/-e[0-9]{13}/', $@image_meta['file'], $img_edit_hash ) &&
strpos( wp_basename( $image_src ), $img_edit_hash[0] ) === false ) {

   return $image;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -2):

Found this:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/bug-with-php-8-0-version/

So one way is to decrease PHP version to 7.4.